# A מין's science: permitted?

Tags: avodah-zarah, masecheth-avodah-zarah

The Talmud (AZ 27b) and in the Tosfot talks about the issur to *frequent* the מינים and to *cure* by them:

> לא ישא ויתן אדם עם המינים ואין מתרפאין מהן אפילו לחיי שעה וכו' שאני מינות דמשכא דאתי לממשך בתרייהו וכו'

**Is another benefit permitted?** For example, to receive a gift from him? Or the man became like an איסור הנאה , a דרבנן extension to the issur to benefit from an avoda zara?

Comment: On what basis do you suspect that learning mathematics could be forbidden? Tosafot discusses interacting with heretics yourself. He states absolutely nothing about benefiting from an idea thought of by a person who may have learned from a theologian.

Comment: `is a mathematical concept, a man's creation, or he just was who Hashem choose to discover one of His world's rules?...` This seems like a subjective question of semantics, that is really unanswerable. A much better question would be whether learning mathematics is included in the statement of Tosafot. (On the basis of my previous comment I cannot fathom how it might be).

Comment: microscopic micro-organismes are not an invention of the man who invented microscope

Comment: @mevaqesh Interesting idea, thank you! +1 But it could be like an איסור הנאה ... edited the question to explain more the problem.

Comment: Why do you assume that IP is owned? Maybe it belongs to the public, in which case your question doesn't start.

Comment: Remember practical questions should be addresses to a rabbi; not an online community.

Comment: Why not just prove the theorems yourself and rename them after Gedolim?

Comment: You didn't quote anything that says that there's an issue hanaah.

Comment: I don't even know what that means. If you want to learn it from a Jew, I'll write the proof down for you. If you mean that it is true, it was true before anyone proved it. Plus many times one person guessed a theorem and another person proved it first. Mathematics never actually finds any new things. We just realize things that were already true.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Right. I just understood that from the issue to *cure* by them. In fact (after reading your answer), the question could be: why it is forbidden to cure, given that it is not a holy thing?...

Comment: @DoubleAA "Mathematics never actually finds any new things. We just realize things that were already true." --> this was indeed one "heter", to say that mathematical concept is not *a man*'s creation. But this is not so obvious; for example, in tora, we sometimes say נעשית תורתו --even not in terms of IP , but...

Comment: @DoubleAA It is easy, for example, to prove by recurrence that sum from 1 to n equals n(n+1)/2. But, if you had not the *goal* (here, the formula), it could be more difficult. So, if we say it is forbidden to *benefit*, just changing the actual development of the proof, is a more little thing...

Comment: Re "But, *now*, the theorem is called on the name of the מין": nota, many theorems in mathematics are named after someone who proved them *not* first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igros Moshe Even HaEzer (1:96) (not on Hebrewbooks) says that it makes sense to say that only about holy things (like writing a Sefer Torah) there is a decree against "leaving a name for the wicked (meaning Apikorsim - heretics)".

Therefore, one's allowed **to use and call medical or mechanical inventions after them**.

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: `Therefore, one's allowed to use and call medical or mechanical inventions after them.` This seems to say one may use an item named after them, or name an item after them. Are you saying that one may use an item invented by them? If not, I don't see how this related to the OP.

Comment: Shmuel, is there any more info on the teshuvah which is relevant, for those of us without an Igros Moshe?

Comment: @yO_ The line in the answer is poorly worded, and should be improved regardless If you happen to be familiar with the IGM and know that intent, that doesn't change that.

Comment: I assume Rav Moshe wrote in lucid Hebrew, rather than less than coherent English. One doesn't use an invention after somebody. | I therefore asked for clarification of whether he meant  use an invention made by somebody @yO_

Comment: @mevaqesh added scan

Comment: Talk about missing the point.